# How to I add rotation to my roller coaster track in blender?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

[image]I want to rotate my track to form different track elements in this dive coaster, but the curve won't allow me to add banking/rotation.I want to achieve this type of effect, where the track rotates around the curve. [image]

Here is my current set up. I can't complete this immelmann without banking the track out.

Answer (score 1):

Select your curve, go into Edit mode. Select a control point, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> to pivot the curve perpendicular to the curve path.

[image]